# Not a valid resolution function for type bit_vector

Tags: vhdl

I need to write a resolution function for a `bit_vector`. I understand that `bit` and `bit_vector` are unresolved types in VHDL, and thus whenever you have multiple drivers for one of these signals, a resolution function is required.

I've successfully implemented a resolution function for a `bit`, however am struggling to implement for a `bit_vector`. This is the error I receive when performing a syntax check: `Line 44: resolve_result is not a valid resolution function for type bit_vector`.

Here is the resolution function:

```
function resolve_result(d: bit_vector) return bit_vector is
    variable combined: bit_vector(15 downto 0) := "0000000000000000";   
    begin 
        combined(7 downto 0) := d(7 downto 0);
        combined(15 downto 8) := d(15 downto 8);
        return combined;
end function resolve_result;

subtype resolve_result_bit_vector is resolve_result bit_vector;
signal rResult: resolve_result_bit_vector;
```

The error, Line 44, is on the `subtype` declaration. This is within the architecture definition of a testbench.

I understand that the `std_ulogic_vector` type will automatically resolve; is changing the type of this signal all that is required? I don't need the functionality of `std_ulogic_vector` hence why I am only using `bit_vector`.

Thank you.

Comment: Why? Why reinvent the wheel? What do you mean with _"I don't need the functionality of std_ulogic_vector"_. You even need `std_logic_vector`, as resolution **_is_** it's main functionality. The u in ulogic stand for "unresolved". And trust me,  you need std_logic, especially whenever you have multiple drivers. Having a lot of functionality doesn't mean you need to use it all.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a custom resolution function. It is surely not synthesisable - unless you have a tri-state, signals cannot be multiply driven in the majority of todays synthesisable resources anyway. Is this a simulation only idea?

Comment: Also note that `std_ulogic_vector` is unresolved and hence has no resolution function. Did you mean `std_logic_vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already wrote a resolution function for type `bit` you probably know what resolution functions look like, what parameter they take and what value they return. And you probably understand that your function cannot be a resolution function for the unconstrained `bit_vector` type. For instance it always returns a 16-bits `bit_vector` and can thus not be used for, let's say, an 8-bits `bit_vector`. It is not the only reason: for such a function the parameter should be an unconstrained array of `bit_vector`, that is, an array of arrays.

Anyway, you don't really need all this. If you already have a resolution function `foobar` for type `bit` simply declare:

```vhdl
subtype resolved_bit_vector is (foobar) bit_vector;
```

If you really want to define a resolution function for 16-bits `bit_vector`, let's say an or-like one, you can try something like:

```vhdl
subtype b16 is bit_vector(15 downto 0);
type b16_array is array(natural range <>) of b16;

function foobar(v: b16_array) return b16 is
  constant n: natural := v'length;
  constant c: b16_array(0 to n - 1) := v;
begin
  if n = 0 then
    return (15 downto 0 => '0');
  elsif n = 1 then
    return c(0);
  else
    return foobar(c(0 to n - 2)) or c(n - 1);
  end if;
end function foobar;

subtype resolved_b16 is foobar b16;
```